# Why Does Spring's @Transactional Help Performance

Tags: java, hibernate, spring

I have a method that can potentially make a lot of calls to a database when validating a list of entities using Hibernate's default traversable resolver. If I annotate it @Transactional, it runs nearly four times faster. A few questions:

1) Why is it faster?

2) How can I replicate that speed increase without making the method transactional? I have absolutely no need to wrap this method in a transaction, and making it transactional is at odds with the real intent of the method.

Comment: maybe transactional changes the number of db writes (reduces it)? You can turn on debug logging for the underlying sql commands to find out.

Comment: This is a read-only situation. I can say, though, that it doesn't seem to reduce the number of times Hibernate's traversable resolver gets instantiated, but it does reduce the amount of time between each instantation.

Comment: I believe it is related to hibernate session - you have to make sure there is only one created for all calls since it is a very expensive object. With `@Transactional` is is always the case, without you can do it manually, with OpenSessionInView filter, possibly with other means. Also there is no reason to avoid `@Transactional` really.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you mean -- I don't deal with sessions explicitly -- but when the method is @Transactional, the application reuses a connection to the DB. Without the annotation, every call to validate an entity uses a new connection. It seems like there should be an easy way to force Hibernate to reuse a connection outside of a transaction.

Comment: Getting connection from the pool is cheap, it would not matter for performance. It's hibernate Session object that is problem here. If you don't manage it somehow, there is a new Session created for each database interaction.

Comment: Any suggestions on how to go about managing sessions? The app currently doesn't reference hibernate sessions at all -- the only place a session factory shows up is in the logs. I'm really not sure how it even gets created.

Comment: How about making it transactional with readOnly=true ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7636/discussion-between-derek-and-mrembisz)

Answer (score 1):

I believe what's going on is that your database logic requires a transaction. If there is a transaction in progress, for example due to Spring creating one based on your annotation, these operation would join it. If there is no transaction in progress, they will have to go through the process of getting connection, starting transaction and, likely, setting up a Hibernate session on each call.

How is this at odds with the intent of your method?

Comment: The logic isn't transactional -- I don't need any sort of atomicity -- it just loops through a bunch of entities to see if they're already in the database. The intent of the method is just to check to make sure all the entities passed in aren't in the DB yet. If the method is @Transactional, it gets marked as RollbackOnly and I can't proceed the way I want to.

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to check and insert in the same transaction? This is a textbook case for desired transaction isolation.